# How to change Tabbed bar background color in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a Tabbed page I am unable to change Bar Background color.
My XAML page look like this

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Saturn;assembly=Saturn"
             BarBackgroundColor="Orange">
<ContantPage></Contantpage>
<ContantPage></Contantpage>
<ContantPage></Contantpage>
<ContantPage></Contantpage>
<ContantPage></Contantpage>
```

But Default color appear Black. How I can change it to Ornage.

Comment: I think you will need to  create a custom renderer for Android and iOS, Here is a good start for android https://github.com/NAXAM/bottomtabbedpage-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colorAccent in styles.xml file but that changes also theme color of your application, this works for Android project.